# Keep the selected treeview row fixed

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The selected row keeps on deselect when the new value is updated in that position. Can we just keep the selection fixed even when the row value changes. Please have a look at the sample code given below, where a treeview row are getting updated every second but as the value gets updated, the row automatically deselects. Please help me with the idea to get the selection fixed even when the value changes. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
import threading

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    
    ccols = ('num1','num2')
    treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=ccols)
    for col in ccols:
        treeview.heading(col, text=col)
    treeview.grid(row=8, column=0)
    
    def sample():
       for i in range(100):
           treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children()) 
           treeview.insert("","end",values=(i,0))
           
       threading.Timer(1.0, sample).start()
       
    sample()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `treeview.insert` returns an identifier so you can use to force a selection by `treeview.selection_set(treeview.insert("", "end", values=(i, 0)))`.

Comment: @HenryYik, Thank you.. but as i can see even the selection is blinking as the row updated and even if i give more row as input everything get selected.. but i want to select the only some rows using control and i want to keep it selected even if the row updates